# Runtime exception/ null pointer exception

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I have many activities very similar to this on and they all work but this one When the activity is opened I get these errors in the logcat.   There are no visible errors in eclipse except for in the log cat so i dont know what to do.

```
    01-01 17:18:00.033: W/dalvikvm(430): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales/com.musicbynumbers.scales.minorMelodic}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at com.musicbynumbers.scales.minorMelodic.onCreate(minorMelodic.java:52)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-01 17:18:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(430):  ... 11 more
01-01 17:23:00.463: I/Process(430): Sending signal. PID: 430 SIG: 9
```

java

```
package com.musicbynumbers.scales;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton; 
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.musicbynumbers.pianoscales.R;

public class minorMelodic extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener  {
    Button aflatmin, amin, bflatmin, bmin, cmin, dflatmin, dmin, eflatmin, emin, fmin, fsharpmin, gmin;  
    ImageButton mainMenu;
    Intent j;
    String scaleName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
        setContentView(R.layout.minormelodic);
        j  = new Intent(this, display.class);
        mainMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagelogo);
        aflatmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aflatmelb);
        amin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.amelb);
        bflatmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bflatmelb);
        bmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmelb);
        cmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmelb);
        dflatmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dflatmelb);
        dmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dharmb);
        eflatmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eflatmelb);
        emin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emelb);
        fmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fmelb);
        fsharpmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fsharpmelb);
        gmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gmelb);
        mainMenu.setOnClickListener(this);
        aflatmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        amin.setOnClickListener(this);
        bflatmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        bmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        cmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        dflatmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        dmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        eflatmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        emin.setOnClickListener(this);
        fmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        fsharpmin.setOnClickListener(this);
        gmin.setOnClickListener(this);



    }






         @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch(arg0.getId()){
                case R.id.imagelogo:
                    Intent i =  new Intent(minorMelodic.this, MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    break;
                case R.id.aflatmelb:
                    scaleName = "aflatmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);

                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.amelb:
                    scaleName = "amelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bflatmelb:
                    scaleName = "bflatmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.bmelb:
                    scaleName = "bmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.cmelb:
                    scaleName = "cmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dflatmelb:
                    scaleName = "dflatmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.dmelb:
                    scaleName = "dmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.eflatmelb:
                    scaleName = "eflatmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.emelb:
                    scaleName = "emelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fmelb:
                    scaleName = "fmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.fsharpmelb:
                    scaleName = "fsharpmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;
                case R.id.gmelb:
                    scaleName = "gmelmin";
                    j.putExtra("key", scaleName);
                    startActivity(j);
                    break;




    }

}
}
```

If anyone could explain how to find where an error happened with the logcat that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you forgot to add a button for `R.id.dharmb` in your layout?

Comment: you know that it's a `NullPointerException` already cause of the prominent **Caused by:** statement. you can look up what that is. right under tells you where to look in order of relevance `...at com.musicbynumbers.scales.minorMelodic.onCreate(minorMelodic.java:52)` here line **52** of the `onCreate` of the minorMelodic class.

Comment: thanks it i put in a button I from a different layout, but how can you tell where the problem is so I don't have to ask here every time there is a problem I can't solve?

Comment: As mango said, under the error it gives you the line number. From there you just have to do a little investigating to see why it is null or whatever the error may be. It gets easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to dmon,codeMagic and mango for answering my questions. I put in a button id from a different layout in the java and that caused the error.